# colsep must be before colspec for @{} to have an effect

Tags: tabularray

Here is a minimal example that took me a long time to identify what was causing this behavior.

In most of the examples in the `tabularray` documentation the `colspec` key is the first to be indicated. However, if you want to use `@{}` to remove spaces before the first column and after the last one, `colspec` must come after `colsep`.

Is this normal, intended behavior or is it a bug?
Or is the `@{}` syntax discouraged with `tabularray`?

Thanks for your insights and have a nice day.

```
%%%% MWE
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colsep=12pt,
  colspec={|@{}lcr@{}|},
}
  a & b & c
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{
  % colspec first, @{} does not work
  colspec={|@{}lcr@{}|},
  colsep=12pt,
  % column{1}={leftsep=0pt},  % needed to have the same effect as @{} before first column
  % column{Z}={rightsep=0pt},  % needed to have the same effect as @{} after last column
}
  a & b & c
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
%%%%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the author of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package, I can confirm that `@{}` is a supported syntax.

Since both `@{}` and `colsep` change the sizes of column separation, it is a normal behaviour that they will overwrite each other.

In more details, `colsep=12pt` is a shortcut for

```
column{1} = {leftsep=12pt,rightsep=12pt},
column{2} = {leftsep=12pt,rightsep=12pt},
column{3} = {leftsep=12pt,rightsep=12pt},
```

while `colspec={|@{}lcr@{}|}` is a shortcut for

```
hline{1},
column{1} = {leftsep=0pt,halign=l},
column{2} = {halign=c},
column{3} = {halign=r,rightsep=0pt},
hline{3},
```

Therefore you need to put `colsep` before `colspec` in this use case.

Comment: I don't see `@{}` mentioned in the `tabularray` documentation, so maybe you can add this explanation tot he manual?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.
Actually I had a problem understanding what `colsep` had an effect on. As `colsep` means `column separation`, I expected that it would only change the space **between 2 columns**. Since there is no column to the left of the first column, I didn't think that `colsep` should also change `leftsep` of the first column. And the same reasoning for the right of the last column.

Comment: Moreover I find it a bit confusing that when one indicates `colsep=12pt` the separation between 2 columns is in fact `24pt` : `12pt` space on the right of column 1 `+` `12pt` on the left of column 2 `= 24pt` separation between column 1 and 2.

I don't know if others would have the same conception as me, and I know it's a mostly semantic misunderstanding based on the key name but as said in the question, it took me a long time to debug my non minimal file.

Comment: A big thank you @L.J.R. for the development of `tabularray` in any case. It's super powerful and thanks to it I can now have all my tables looking exactly like what I want.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum You are right. Although many aspects in `tabularray` are the same as those in `tabular`, it is still better to make the documentation seft-contained.

Comment: @Xorios As a new package, `tabularray` try to follow many aspects of similar old packages. The `colsep` in `tabularray` is similar to `\tabcolsep` in `tabular`.